# Can any function be decomposed as sum of Gaussians?

Tags: neural-network, gaussian, wavelet, decomposition, continuous-fourier

- In Fourier series, any function can be decomposed as sum of sine and 
  cosine
- In neural networks, any function can be decomposed as weighted sum over logistic functions. (A one layer neural network)
- In wavelet transforms, any function can be decomposed as weighted sum of Haar functions

Is there also such property for decomposition into mixture of Gaussians? If so, is there a proof?

Comment: Wavelet transforms are much more than just Haar functions.

Comment: You may also want to check out https://math.stackexchange.com/ and https://mathoverflow.net/. I tried to edit my answer to give more context, but it is hard to do here because there's no latex/mathjax in the markdown.  

If you're interested, you can ask a similar question there and I'll try to answer?

Answer (score 5):

There's a theorem, the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_real_version), which gives conditions for when a family of functions can approximate any continuous function. You need

- an algebra of functions (closed under addition, subtraction, and
  multiplication)
- the constant functions
- and you need the functions to separate points:

  - (for any two distinct points you can find a a function that assigns them different values)

You can approximate a constant function with increasingly wide gaussians. You can time-shift gaussians to separate points. So if you form an algebra out of gaussians, you can approximate any continuous function with them.

Comment: +1 This answer is significantly more thorough than the top-voted answer. I've referenced your answer [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/do-the-cc-pc-def2-basis-sets-mathematically-converge-to-the-cbs-limit-assuming/9682?noredirect=1#comment20415_9682) in case you're interested! Perhaps you can write a better answer for that user who seems to be much more interested in the mathematical convergence properties than the typical user of that Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 3):

If the sum allows to be infinite, then the answer is Yes. Please refer to Yves Meyer's book of "Wavelet and Operators", section 6.6, lemma 10.

Comment: Note that this lemma is for complex functions expressed as sum of positive Gaussians with complex coefficients, so it might take a bit more work to show (if true) that any positive function can be written as a sum of positive Gaussians with positive coeffcients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Decomposing any function to a sum of any kind of Gaussians is possible, since it can be decomposed to a sum of [Dirac functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) :) (and Dirac is a Gaussian where the variance approaches zero).

Some more interesting questions would be:

- Can any function be decomposed to a sum of non-zero variance Gaussians, with a given, constant variance, that are defined around varying centers?
- Can any function be be decomposed to a sum of non-zero variance Gaussians, all having 0 as the center, but defined with alternating variances?

[The Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to answer these questions though.